# mysql - Database organization for representing location

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I need to create database which will contain the following entities in country:

1. Regions

   2. Municipalities

      - *Now comes the hard part for me:*
      - Municipality can also be city, where city can (but not always) have its own municipalities.
      - Municipality can have several cities.
      - Municipality in both cases contains several settlements

I wanted to create several tables, for example:

- regions (region_id, region_name)
- municipalities (municipality_id, municipality_name, region_id).
- cities (city_id, city_name, region_id)
- city_municipalities (city_municipality_id, city_municipality_name, city_id)
- settlements (settlement_id, settlement_name, municipality_id, city_municipality_id)

  - i think that here i make problem. There would be a lot of NULLs for `municipality_id` or `city_municipality_id`, since i cant have both field filled.

**But right now it comes to my mind to have two tables organized like this:**

- geo_entity(geo_id, geo_name, geo_type_id, parent)
- geo_entities_type (geo_type_id, geo_type_name)
- this table will contain definitions of what geo_entity entry is, like:

  - 1 Region
  - 2 Municipality
  - 3 City
  - 4 City Municipality
  - 5 Settlement

**What should i stick to? Do you have a better approach and which one?**

Comment: The two approaches you mentioned are the basic options you have with relational DB, there are no any completely different ones. They both have their advantages and disadvantages. Like first is more strict (you can't make one region child of another region for example), but second is more flexible. You have to think about your use cases and decide which fits better for these use cases. Also note that graph DB (like [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/)) might be a better choice for this task.

Comment: The problem with pretry much all design related questions is that we do not know how and what for the described component of the sw is going to be used. Without these background information how do you expect anyone to give you any useful answer?

Comment: Well I would like to limit users to enter proper information in database, from list of options (first they would choose region, then municipality/city, address etc). Mainly database will be used in system like CRM, where sales team should have option to list specific entries based on their location.

Comment: Are your Entities "nested"?  Or overlapping?  If nested, build a hierarchy.  If overlapping, use many-to-many relation table(s).

Comment: Entities would be nested like hierarchy.

Comment: just copy geonames and move on

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean by that?